# nginx/haproxy performance with many lines of configuration

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I'm planning to build an environment that can programmatically setup child servers and sandbox them using nginx/ha. First I would ensure `*.example.com` points to nginx/ha. Then, for example, I would setup app `x` to only serve from `x.example.com` and then to allow app `x` to talk to a specific method of app `y`, I would add the following config:

```
server { 
    server_name x.example.com;

    location /y/allowed/method/ {
        proxy_pass y.example.com;
    }
}
```

(And the corresponding haproxy config if I were to use ha)

My question is, how many servers and locations like this could I include in a given instance of nginx or haproxy while still maintaining high performance ? I know I can move access restrictions up a layer into the applications themselves though I'd prefer it at the network layer

Edit:
Answer is in the comments below. Essentially, if the config can fit in RAM, performance won't be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate nginx config with many server blocks (one per domain) like this:

```
server { 
    server_name x.example.com;

    location /y/allowed/method/ {
        proxy_pass y;
    }
}
```

Reference:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: True, thats better than domain is ... I'll update the question

Nevertheless, my question still stands, how many rules can nginx handle ? For example, what if I had 1000 servers, each with 10 different locations to proxy ?

Comment: It depends on how many memory you have multiplied by how many modules you have compiled in nginx.

Comment: 1000 servers x 10 locations must be ok. In fact I saw folks who have tens times bigger configuration.

Comment: So it can handle 100,000 locations without much performance impact? I guess it would be fine if it hashes each server+location ? I'm still curious to what the limit is (and for arguments sake, we'll say its a vanilla nginx server with default modules) ?

I can do some tests though I was hoping someone knew...

Comment: It uses hash tables for `server_name`s (see: [`server_names_hash_bucket_size`](http://nginx.org/r/server_names_hash_bucket_size)) and some sort of radix trees for `location`s, unless they specified by regular expression. The only limit is amount of RAM.